# If statement in Postman tests

Tags: javascript, html, json, postman

I work in Postman and I want to build the test construction like that:

```
var login_status = pm.environment.get("LOGIN_STATUS");
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.test("TESTS", function () {
    if (login_status === 1) {
        pm.expect...(test 1);
    }else if (login_status === 2) {
                pm.expect...(test 2);
    }else if (login_status === 3) {
                pm.expect...(test 3);
```

but it doesn't work for me as I want.

In my logic, Postman should check the login status and use only one pm.expect... accordingly to login_status value.

How can I use the if statement in Postman?

Comment: What is not working? Can you please provide more details? Does it throw error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison operator you are using is returning `false` as it's checking for the same `type`, try using `==` rather than `===`.

The values stored in the Postman environment file is a `string` and you're doing a strict equal against a `number`, in the test.

You could also try changing the `number` value to a `string` value like this `login_status === "1"` or use strict inequality so the type you use doesn't matter, like this `login_status !== 2`.

You could even just use a `parseInt()` function when you get the value from the file.

```
parseInt(pm.environment.get("LOGIN_STATUS"))
```

It's completely up to you and the way you want to construct the check.

More information about the comparison operator can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity

Comment: You're welcome. :) Do you want to accept that answer?